# ID a green ceramic component from a tachometer?

Tags: identification, vintage, tachometer

This component is from a 1960-70 vintage boat tachometer.

[image: Mystery component]

It's about 1.25" long.  It generates not a single reading on my 11-function multimeter (including capacitance). I may have fried it removing it from the circuit board.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: An RC combination maybe. 1nF, 10Ω, 250V

Comment: 1uF 10% 250V. Per comment on previous answer except now we can see the value.

Answer (score 3):

It might be a 1uF +/-10% 250V film capacitor.

Eg. (0.1uF cap with similar markings from [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07BL4T67H) website [image]

Check your meter's capacitance range on a known-good part if  you don't use it frequently.

Comment: excellent. Thank you. Checking now!

Comment: And you called it.  .95uF

Answer (score 0):

The capacitance might be to small for most multimeters that I know of.
I would recommend getting a good quality dedicated bench-top capacitance meter.

Note: I’ve had much better experience and accuracy with bench-top meters than with cheap handheld meters(I have also had a similar Experience with bench top oscilloscopes cheap handheld scopes are just not worth it.) however this post does not discriminate against owning a good handheld multimeter. (:

Comment: Thanks for the advice. In this case it was operator error.  I'd missed the fact that the meter has two slots for cap leads. It only goes to 20uF, but that's enough in this case.